# "private" comments in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I would like to write "private" comments in Eclipse while working on Java projects. In other words, I would like to write comments associated with areas in the Java classes that only I can see but other developers working on the project cannot. The comments therefore cannot be regular comments in the source code. Ideally I would select an area on a Java source file and have a view in the perspective allowing me to write and read my comments associated with the selected area. Those comments should be persisted in a file(s) outside of the Java source files of the project.

I understand that as other developers modify the Java code my comments might become stale and I will have to eventually have to work to alleviate this problem. I am not worried about the persistence right now, either.

How do I handle the Eclipse part of the challenge, i.e. create my own view in/to which I can write/read comments and have it associated with locations in the source files? Or, can I display comments lines in the source files that are not saved along with the source so that they are "private"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like what you can already do with the Bookmarks View, aside from the text presentation in the view itself being rather limited.